# How does Shazam capture Spotify audio data via headphones?

Tags: android, audio, spotify

Since Spotify opted out of the Android AudioPlaybackCapture API, other apps cannot capture audio played via headphones using this API. How does Shazam do it then?

Is there any other way to capture audio by a third party app that is played over headphones?

In addition to The AudioPlaybackCapture API I have also tried Spotify's media data broadcasts, but no success either.